# Accept or reject a call on bluetooth device (like smart watch) from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

In some of the Smart watches like pebble and meta watch,it is possible to accept and reject calls on the smart watch.how the call related info be transferred between iPhone and bluetooth device using MAP or PBAP. I would like to accept the call from the bluetooth device similar to earphone where I can accept the call via bluetooth.

Is there any legitimate api or any pointers to accomplish this ?

EDIT

Metawatch has inbuilt microphone and speaker and it implements HFP and PBAP.If smart watch has in built microphone and speaker and if it implements HFP,calls can be accepted from the watch,but Pebble does not have in built microphone and speaker. Still Pebble is able to accept the call and route it to headset. Pebble supports HFP,MAP,AVRCP and SPP on iOS and it is an MFi.How can the same be implemented in an app?

Comment: Probably Pebble has a HFP(handsfree) profile for bluetooth with which watch can be notified via certain AT commands for incoming call and other info. Watch can respond to accept/reject calls. Phone acts as a AG(audio gateway) and headsets(or pebble) acts as a HF(handsfree) device

Comment: CTCallStateIncoming notifies about incoming call,but how would I get the caller number?

Comment: Ram, you can google for HFP 1.5 spec, i am not an iOS dev so can't point out the code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own application to intercept incoming call events and using your own communication mechanism (over Bluetooth) communicate this info to your device (i.e. watch)
With this you can fairly easily pass incoming call indication to the watch, 
Accepting call is more involved as you need to have the ability to intercept an ongoing bluetooth profile connection, Android has the BluetoothHeadset Class that provides some capability, with iOS there is no straight forway way (but it is possible)

Comment: Deninis: Is there any API that notifies about the incoming call and the caller number so that I can display this on external bluetooth device. Is there any API to accept the call Programatically.
The answer might be no for both,but there should be some commands or other ways to  achieve this.Any info on this.